# OpenCV - body contour artmpits detection

Tags: python, c++, opencv, image-recognition

Good day.

I'm trying to analyze a human body contour using openCV. I already recognized head (topmost point of contour), left and right arms (leftmost and rightmost poitns), left and right legs (I split a body contour into two halves and found bottommost points). I also have shoulder points (topmost points between corresponding leg and foot).

But I also need to recognize armpits and I have no idea how to. Here's what I already have (red outline is my contour. I'm working with HSV image, if that even matters):

[image]

Comment: What assumptions can you make about the pose? Is there a minimal/maximal angle between the arms and body, or is it just a general pose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use findContour() and then convex hull here which could serve you better.